# Apache Http Digest Authentication using Java

Tags: java, apache, md5, http-authentication, digest

I am currently working on a Java project and I can't get the http digest authentication working. I tried using the Apache website, but it didn't help. I have a site that requires HTTP digest authentication.

```
        DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        String hostUrl = "http://somewebsite.com";
        String postUrl = "http://somewebsite.com/request";
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(postUrl);
        String username = "hello";
        String password = "world";
        HttpHost targetHost = new HttpHost(hostUrl);

        httpclient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(
                new AuthScope(hostUrl, AuthScope.ANY_PORT),
                new UsernamePasswordCredentials(username, password));

        AuthCache authCache = new BasicAuthCache();

        DigestScheme digestAuth = new DigestScheme();

        digestAuth.overrideParamter("realm", "some realm");

        digestAuth.overrideParamter("nonce", "whatever");
        authCache.put(targetHost, digestAuth);

        BasicHttpContext localcontext = new BasicHttpContext();
        localcontext.setAttribute(ClientContext.AUTH_CACHE, authCache);

        // List<NameValuePair> nvps = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        // nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", "shirwa99@gmail.com"));
        // nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", "example"));
        // httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps));
        HttpResponse response2 = httpclient.execute(httpPost);
```

Comment: any solution for that?

Answer (score 2):

This code works for me pretty well:

```
protected static void downloadDigest(URL url, FileOutputStream fos)
  throws IOException {
  HttpHost targetHost = new HttpHost(url.getHost(), url.getPort(), url.getProtocol());
  CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
  HttpClientContext context = HttpClientContext.create();

  String credential = url.getUserInfo();
  if (credential != null) {
    String user = credential.split(":")[0];
    String password = credential.split(":")[1];

    CredentialsProvider credsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
    credsProvider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY,
      new UsernamePasswordCredentials(user, password));
    AuthCache authCache = new BasicAuthCache();
    DigestScheme digestScheme = new DigestScheme();
    authCache.put(targetHost, digestScheme);

    context.setCredentialsProvider(credsProvider);
    context.setAuthCache(authCache);
  }

  HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url.getPath());

  CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(targetHost, httpget, context);

  try {
    ReadableByteChannel rbc = Channels.newChannel(response.getEntity().getContent());
    fos.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);
  } finally {
    response.close();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this code from apache httpClient 4.3.3

```
final HttpHost targetHost = new HttpHost("localhost", 8080, "http");
    final CredentialsProvider credsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
    credsProvider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY,
            new UsernamePasswordCredentials(user, password));

    final AuthCache authCache = new BasicAuthCache();
    DigestScheme digestAuth = new DigestScheme();
    digestAuth.overrideParamter("realm", "some-realm");
    digestAuth.overrideParamter("nonce", "whatever");
    authCache.put(targetHost, digestAuth);

    // Add AuthCache to the execution context
    HttpClientContext context = HttpClientContext.create();
    context.setAuthCache(authCache);
HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("/");
CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(targetHost , httpget, context );
```

Please can you give me the site which requires HTTP digest authentication?

Comment: did you find any online webservice to test your stuff?

Comment: I use http://httpbin.org. There is a digest auth endpoint to test. But I still get a 401 back using the code above. Is this snippet working for anyone using Digest Auth?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code from [Apache](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/httpcomponents/oac.hc3x/trunk/src/examples/AlternateAuthenticationExample.java?view=markup) :

```
   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            client.getState().setCredentials(
                new AuthScope("myhost", 80, "myrealm"),
                new UsernamePasswordCredentials("username", "password"));
            // Suppose the site supports several authetication schemes: NTLM and Basic
            // Basic authetication is considered inherently insecure. Hence, NTLM authentication
            // is used per default

            // This is to make HttpClient pick the Basic authentication scheme over NTLM & Digest
            List authPrefs = new ArrayList(3);
            authPrefs.add(AuthPolicy.BASIC);
            authPrefs.add(AuthPolicy.NTLM);
            authPrefs.add(AuthPolicy.DIGEST);
            client.getParams().setParameter(AuthPolicy.AUTH_SCHEME_PRIORITY, authrefs);

            GetMethod httpget = new GetMethod("http://myhost/protected/auth-required.html");

            try {
                int status = client.executeMethod(httpget);
                // print the status and response
                System.out.println(httpget.getStatusLine());
                System.out.println(httpget.getResponseBodyAsString());
            } finally {
                // release any connection resources used by the method
                httpget.releaseConnection();
            }            
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Tipp: do not use HTTP Digest :) It is not secure at all. Over HTTPS it has not point.

If you must, below is a code that works with parsing the `WWW-Authenticate` header.

This is tested with the following dependency (i use `gradle`):

```
compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpclient', version: '4.5.6'
```

The code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import org.apache.http.Header;
import org.apache.http.HttpHost;
import org.apache.http.auth.AuthScope;
import org.apache.http.auth.MalformedChallengeException;
import org.apache.http.auth.UsernamePasswordCredentials;
import org.apache.http.client.AuthCache;
import org.apache.http.client.CredentialsProvider;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.CloseableHttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.protocol.HttpClientContext;
import org.apache.http.impl.auth.DigestScheme;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicAuthCache;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicCredentialsProvider;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

public class DigestExample {

  private final static String uri = "http://my.digest.based.auth.url.com";
  private static HttpHost target;

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {    

    setup();
    if (target == null) {
      System.out.println("Setup was unsuccesfull");
      return;
    }
    Header challengeHeader = getAuthChallengeHeader();
    if (challengeHeader == null) {
      System.out.println("Setup was unsuccesfull");
      return;
    }

    // NOTE: challenge is reused for subsequent HTTP GET calls (typo corrected)
    getWithDigestAuth(challengeHeader, "/", "/schema");

  }

  private static void setup() throws MalformedURLException {
    URL url = new URL(uri);
    target = new HttpHost(url.getHost(), url.getPort(), url.getProtocol());
  }

  private static Header getAuthChallengeHeader() {
    try (CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault()) {
      CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(new HttpGet(uri));
      return response.getFirstHeader("WWW-Authenticate");
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      return null;
    }
  }

  private static void getWithDigestAuth(Header challengeHeader, String... requests)
      throws IOException {

    CredentialsProvider credsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
    credsProvider.setCredentials(
        new AuthScope(target.getHostName(), target.getPort()),
        new UsernamePasswordCredentials("user", "pass"));

    try (CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom()
        .setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credsProvider)
        .build()) {

      // Create AuthCache instance
      AuthCache authCache = new BasicAuthCache();
      // Generate DIGEST scheme object, initialize it and add it to the local
      // auth cache
      DigestScheme digestAuth = new DigestScheme();
      digestAuth.processChallenge(challengeHeader);
      authCache.put(target, digestAuth);

      // Add AuthCache to the execution context
      HttpClientContext localContext = HttpClientContext.create();
      localContext.setAuthCache(authCache);

      for (String request : requests) {
        System.out.println("Executing request to target " + target + request);
        try (CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient
            .execute(target, new HttpGet(request), localContext)) {
          System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
          System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
          System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()));
        } catch (Exception e) {
          System.out.println("Error while executing HTTP GET request");
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
    } catch (MalformedChallengeException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```